# In Jenkins, How to receive parameter value on different variable name

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins parameterized project, is there a way to receive the variable in different name?

for e.g:

JOB_A:
  sends parameter `FOO='myfoo'` when it calls JOB_B

JOB_B:
Is there a way to receive it on different name, say 'BAR', so it will be  `BAR='myfoo'`, I know this can be done with `BAR=$FOO in Build/Execute shell`, I am here to find if there is any option to do this in `General/This project is parameterized` section.

Comment: Why don't you simply rename the parameter in Job B ?

Answer (score 0):

On JOB_A, in 'Trigger/call builds on other progects' find 'Predefined Parameters' from 'Add Parameters' drop-down. You just want to put this:

```
BAR=${FOO}
```

[Click to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkDtK.png)